# How to import xml file in servlet xml file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have separate xml file which has jdbc , mysql details.

Now i don't know how include file in servlet xml.

i tried this but didn't worked

```
<import resource="jdbc-context.xml">
```

Comment: Is it a jdbc datasource ? or a custom xml source ? Could you provide its structure ?

Comment: yes its jdbc data source

Comment: What do the logs say about this?

Comment: i found it i didn't close the import tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says: "All location paths are relative to the definition file doing the importing"

Is this the case?